# Maven repository blocking specific ip addresses?

Tags: java, maven, wget

I am trying to download the file  http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/aether/aether-api/1.13.1/aether-api-1.13.1.jar as part of a maven build by my ci server but I get the error:

```
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/aether/aether-api/1.13.1/aether-api-1.13.1.jar
01-Nov-2012 08:44:26    Nov 01, 2012 8:44:26 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
01-Nov-2012 08:44:26    INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
01-Nov-2012 08:44:26    Nov 01, 2012 8:44:26 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
01-Nov-2012 08:44:26    INFO: Retrying request
```

After locating this error in the logs I tried to download this artefact by hand with wget which  didn't work also. Further investigation revealed that downloading form another server form this provider (different ip/same ip-range) is not possible either.

downloading this file to servers form other providers was successful at the same time.

I was able to ping repo.maven.apache.org so the server was reachable.

Is it possible that the ip-address of my ci-server is blocked for download?
Do I have to move my ci-server to a different provider?

(atm my ci-server is hosted at jiffybox/domainfactory, if that helps answering the question)

Comment: Similar (?) problem: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-21

Answer (score 0):

There are currently serious problems with maven's CDN provider, see

- the support forum at

  - https://getsatisfaction.com/sonatype/topics/unable_to_dowload_maven_jetty_plugin_version_6_1_26_from_central
- current issue reports at

  - https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-257
  - https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-259
  - https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-260

So obviously they are working on it.

The only workaround for me was to download through a VPN tunnel.